# How can I uninstall a printer that doesn't provide the 'remove' option?

Tags: windows-7, printer, administration

I have Windows 7 (32-bit) and installed a printer. During the setup something went wrong and now I have a printer entry in the list where I can just *Resolve Problems* but not *Remove* (there is no *Remove* button or entry in the context menu).

By trying to resolve the problem I was not successful (the result was always printer is off even it is on and connected).

Is there a general (admin) way to remove such entries e.g. in the registry or by a tool?

UPDATE:
Ok first, no I can NOT press a delete key. If the menu and the context entry not available the delete key doesn't work too!

To see what I see, here the screenshot:

[image]

Sorry for a Germany UI!
To understand the image. I like to remove the marked printer and the one marked as default printer works. I doesn't make any different if this one is installed or not.

UPDATE 2

Ok to make it more clear does anybody now a methode to remove an entry here? e.g. somewhere in the registry?

Comment: Can you not just restart the spooler service, and delete the printer (using the Delete button on your keyboard)?

Answer (score 6):

To remove a printer do the following:

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. Click Hardware and Sound.
3. Click Device Manager

Find your printer, right click on it and click **Uninstall**. If you can't find your printer click the view menu and select 'Show hidden devices'. Now you should be able to find it. On the other hand, you should be able to remove the printer from:

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. Click Hardware and Sound.
3. Click Devices and Printers
4. Right click on printer and click 'Remove device'.

Comment: Sorry but this entry is not listed in the device manager even if the hidden flag is set.

Comment: Mine was under "Other devices". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general way to completely remove a printer:

Go to the Printers control panel. First delete the printer (click on it and press Delete). Now click on any other printer and then click the Print Server Properties link that appears. Click the Drivers tab and remove any instances of the printer from the list.

Comment: Sorry as already try to explain, i can not delete the printer and during the setup I did not reach the driver setup, therefore there is not related driver entry.

Answer (score 0):

If the printer was not installed correctly, usually with a missing driver, the printer can still show up in the devices and printers list and not have the option to remove the printer. To remove this printer:

1) Open Device Manager (must be as administrator)

2) Expand Other Devices

3) Right-click and uninstall the unsuccessful device

This will remove the printer from the printer list

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I added a new printer to the USB Printer port and chose to overwrite the existing driver and select the printer as default. Everything is restored and I can delete the printer if I choose.